# Extract character values from strings of different lengths in a vector in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have a vector that looks like the following:

```
**name**
a1
a2
a3
b1_z
b2_3z
b32z
```

I would like the output to only include the letters in each of these strings, not any numbers or symbols. Like this:

```
**name**
a
a
a
bz
bz
bz
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
df$name <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$name, "[a-z]+")
```

I get this result:

```
**name**
a
a
a
c("b", "z")
c("b", "z")
c("b", "z")
```

How do I combine the values that are two separate strings into a single string? In particular, how do I do this when some of the values in the vector already contain only one string? I am also open to other solutions for extracting characters from strings that get around this issue.

Comment: If it's only digits and underscores you want to remove then `gsub("\\d|_", "", df$name)` will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `gsub` like below

```
df$name <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]","",df$name)
```

where non-alphabet characters are replaced by `""`.

We will get

```
> df
  name
1    a
2    a
3    a
4   bz
5   bz
6   bz
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(name = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1_z", "b2_3z", "b32z"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using the `gsub` function:

```
vals = c('a1', 'a2', 'b1_z', 'b2_3z')
df = data.frame(vals)

df$name = gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", df$vals)
print(df)
```

Output will look like this:

```
  name
1    a
2    a
3   bz
4   bz
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(df$name, "[0-9_]+")
#[1] "a"  "a"  "a"  "bz" "bz" "bz"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1_z", "b2_3z", "b32z"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```